Reformulating Mixed-integer Bilevel program into MINLP
I am working on a problem where I have this Bilevel programming problem:
$ Max \quad a+b $ 
$s.t.\quad \quad \alpha \in \{0, 0.5, 0.8\} $
$\quad \quad \quad \; \ a = min \ \lambda$
$ \quad  \quad \; \  \quad s.t. \quad \ F(\alpha,\lambda) = \alpha \lambda^3 + \alpha \lambda^2 -3 = 0$
$  \quad \; \  \quad \qquad \; \;\ \quad\lambda \geq 0$
$\quad \; \  \quad \quad b = max \ \lambda$
$\quad \; \  \quad  \quad  s.t. \quad \ F(\alpha,\lambda) = \alpha \lambda^3 + \alpha \lambda^2 -3 = 0$
$ \quad \; \  \quad  \qquad \; \;\ \quad\lambda < 0$
Where the upper problem contains integer variables (here $\alpha$) and the two lower problems contain a polynomial $F(\alpha,\lambda)$.
I tried solving this problem, however, I couldn't find a solver capable of solving these kinds of problems. I tried using the pao package, a wrapper for pyomo, but it can only solve bilinear/quadratic subproblems.
I have two questions:
Is there a solver than can solve these kind of problems straight away? Is there a way to reformulate this problem into a MINLP?
$F$ will always be a polynomial, but may look different or contain higher-order terms.

I assume that the actual problem will have multiple integer variables and that the $F$ polynomial will use all of the integer variables as coefficients. How large would the set of all combinations of integer variables be? Brute force enumeration might be your only shot.

You say that $\alpha$ is an integer variable but also that $\alpha\in{0,0.5,0.8}$.  Please clarify.

@RobPratt - ok, discrete variable then. But {0,5,8} also works. Was just an example

@prubin Yes, you are right. Around 5^20. I thought about exhaustive search, but ideally I find a better solution.
Actually, the polynomial is the characteristic polynomial of a matrix - a symbolic matrix. So my question is really, can I optimize the symbols in the matrix (chosen from a discrete set), so that the eigenvalues (roots of the characteristic polynomial) fulfil some property. Here I want to maximize the difference between the smallest positive and largest negative eigenvalue.

For fixed numbers $p$ and $q$ of distinct positive and negative eigenvalues, respectively, you can express the problem directly as a single-level MINLP: maximize $\lambda_{q+1}-\lambda_q$ subject to $F(\alpha,\lambda_i)=0$ for all $i$ and $\lambda_1<\dots<\lambda_q<0<\lambda_{q+1}<\dots<\lambda_{p+q}$.  To enforce strict inequalities, replace $<$ with $+\epsilon \le$ for some small positive constant tolerance $\epsilon$.

could you explain what the given signature is? Would I have to know the roots of the polynomial (dependent on alpha) in advance?

It means that $p$ is the number of positive eigenvalues and $q$ is the number of negative eigenvalues. You would solve the problem once for each choice of $(p,q)$, and  the roots are part of the output.

Got it. That's definitely helpful, thanks!
